# How do you pass a pointer to an object to a function? C++

Tags: c++, object, reference

Lets say in main() I create an object pointer called BOB from a class called TheBuilder and I do this like this

```
TheBuilder *BOB = new TheBuilder();
```

Now lets say I have a function that I want to pass this to called helloWorld inside of main. How do I pass this BOB pointer to TheBuilder object? How do I call it and what does the parameter list for helloWorld() look like?

I want to be able to modify data inside of the object that BOB is pointing to inside of the member function helloWorld.

I know it probably has some '*' or '&' but I don't know where to put them.

Thanks

Comment: Consider a C++ tutorial.

Comment: ^ aha.. come on.. lets help the guy. I was once in his position and indeed had to read a book to figure it out. But still was confused by it all until I asked someone on stackoverflow! who knows today he might finally know when to you use what if we give him a short lending hand! After all he's just asking for a quick explanation so he can make the right decision of which one to use :D

Comment: This is too basic a question to be asked. I would recommend you reading a short tutorial about C++, you will find all the answers, most probably on the second or third paragraph.

Comment: It is a "practical, answerable problem that is unique to the programming profession", to quote the FAQ.  But it's not likely to help future visitors. In fact to have questions like this in the database just reduces the quality of the search function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class TheBuilder
{
    <class def>
}

void helloWorld (TheBuilder* obj)
{
    <do stuff to obj, which points at BOB>;
}

int main ()
{
    TheBuilder *BOB = new TheBuilder();
    helloWorld (BOB);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, user1347439 beat me to it

Comment: Thank you, I was trying that earlier but forgot to do void helloWorld(TheBuilder *) in my prototype because I had the function after main.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main()
{
    TheBuilder *BOB = new TheBuilder();
    helloWorld(BOB);
    if (BOB->canWeBuildIt)
        printf("yes we can!");
    delete BOB;
    return 0;
}

void helloWorld(TheBuilder *bob)
{
    bob->canWeBuildIt = true;
}
```

Comment: That's pretty funny, thanks haha

Answer (score 0):

```
void doSomething1(int x){ 
  //code 
}
```

This one passes the variable by value, whatever happens inside the function, the original variable doesn't change

```
void doSomething2(int *x){ 
  //code 
}
```

Here you pass a variable of type pointer to integer. So when accessing the number you should use *x for the value or x for the address

```
void doSomething3(int &x){ 
  //code 
}
```

Here it's like the first one, but whatever happens inside the function, the original variable will be changed as well

So in your case you would write

```
void helloWorld (TheBuilder* object){
    //Do stuff with BOB
}

void main (){
    TheBuilder *BOB = new TheBuilder();
    helloWorld (BOB);
}
```

Comment: What would calling each of those functions look like? I know by value obviously but what about the other two?

Comment: void helloWorld(TheBuilder* object){ //code}
and 
void helloWorld(TheBuilder &object){ //code}
it all depends what you want happening. refer to the individual explanations for each of those cases that tell you what happens to the variable whether you use the & or * signs.

Comment: and calling them... its the same as the first one. you simple pass the value in and the rest is handled inside the method when the instance is passed. You still call it like so helloWorld (BOB). Obviously the method names need to be different if you had all three accepting the same instance but behave differently based on * and & as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter list would include a `TheBuilder *` parameter.  For example:

`void helloWorld(TheBuilder *theBuilder) { ... }`

And to call it:

`helloWorld(BOB);`

Answer (score 0):

If `helloWorld` is a member function, then you don't need to pass any object pointer: there is an implicit pointer, called `this`, which points to the object on which you invoked the member function:

```
#include <iostream>

class TheBuilder
{
  public:
    void helloWorld();

    std::string name_;
};

void TheBuilder::helloWorld()
{
    //Here, you can use "this" to refer to the object on which
    //"helloWorld" is invoked

    std::cout << this->name_ << " says hi!\n";

    //In fact, you can even omit the "this" and directly use member variables
    //and member functions

    std::cout << name << " says hi!\n";
}

int main()
{
    TheBuilder alice; //constructs an object TheBuilder named alice
    alice.name_ = "Alice";

    TheBuilder bob; //constructs an object TheBuilder named bob
    bob.name_ = "Bob";

    alice.helloWorld(); //In helloWorld, "this" points to alice
                        //prints "Alice says hi!"

    bob.helloWorld(); //In helloWorld, "this" points to bob
                      //prints "Bob says hi!"
}
```

In fact, a member function is pretty much like a free function with an implicit parameter corresponding to the object being manipulated. When you write the following code:

```
struct MyClass
{
    int myMemberFunction() {...}
};

MyClass obj;
obj.myMemberFunction();
```

the code generated by the compiler is equivalent to the following:

```
int myMemberFunction(MyClass * this) {...}

MyClass obj;
myMemberFunction(&obj);
```

but you don't need to bother about that. All you need to understand is that a member function (a method in object-oriented terminology) is invoked *on an object*, and manipulates the object it is invoked on (for example, it can modify its member variables (fields)). In a member function, you can access the current object members either by using their names directly, or you can be explicit and use the `this` pointer.